# php search in database with string

Tags: php, database, arrays, string

I want to search in a database with variable positions. The variables are created here:

```
&numbers  //= user input
&naar    // = user input

$number = range($numbers+1, $naar -1); //define the range between the inputs
foreach ($number as $key=>$val){
$number[$key] = $letter.$val;}         //define the array
$string = implode (' ',$number);       // make a string from the array
```

This works fine. The output is a string that contains a minimum of 0 outputs and a maximun of 7 outputs. For example: `A2 A3 A4 A5`

I want the database to search if something is at one of the generated positions. Ive got this already:

```
  $query="select chess_id from stelling where positie=\"".$number."\"";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  $spring = 0;
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)                
        {
        $spring = mysql_result($result, 0);
        }
    echo "$spring";
```

With this code only the last generated $string output will be checked. How can i let the database check all generated string code? For example:

```
$string = `A2 A3 A4 A5`
$query="select chess_id from stelling where positie=\"".$number."\"";
```

will only  check `A5`

sample rows from table:

wt,A1
wp,A2
wl,A3
wq,A4

Comment: Can you post some sample rows from the table, and which ones should be selected?

Comment: I suspect what you really want is `WHERE position IN ("A2", "A3", ...)`.

Comment: Or `WHERE position BETWEEN "A2" AND "A5"`.

Comment: Do you understand that `positie = "A2 A3 A4 A5"` compares the entire string to the column value, it doesn't look for partial matches? This is beginner stuff.

Comment: yes i understand that, but i dont understand how i can compare parts of te string.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not shure what exactly is your problem but why don't you use IN statement ?

```
$string = '(`' . implode('`, `',$number) . '`)';   
$query="select chess_id from stelling where positie IN {$string}";
```

Comment: I get the following warning: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. I changed my line of code with yours. thanks

Comment: maybe there are no matches in DB. also check the value of $string before anything